# C++ Qt - QString remove() regex between {brackets}

Tags: c++, qt, qstring, qregexp, qtcore

I have tried the following regular expressions to remove {anything} between brackets (and hopefully the brackets themselves)!

```
    mystr.remove(QRegExp("\\{(.*?)\\}"));
    mystr.remove(QRegExp("\{(.*?)\}"));
```

Nothing is removed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.*?` is invalid. Try the following code:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QRegExp>

int main()
{
    QString mystr = "te{foo}st";
    qDebug() << mystr.remove(QRegExp("\\{(.*)\\}"));

    return 0;
}
```

#### Compilation

This may not be the exact command you need to run, so try to adjust the concept for your particular scenario.

```
g++ -I/usr/include/qt/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt -fPIC -lQt5Core main.cpp && ./a.out
```

Output: `"test"`

Comment: I had the same issue as @y2k, and after searching for a while I came across this answer. Not understanding why .*? was invalid for QT I did a follow up search and found out that .*? is only currently invalid because QT doesn't support non-greedy expressions: http://qt-project.org/wiki/Regexp_engine_in_Qt5

Comment: Just to add that Qt supports non-greedy expressions, but not in the regexp code. See QRegExp::setMinimal.